# Quick sort implementation crash

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

so I am implementing quick sort and I get an error once  I start the program. I think that logic-wise everything should be okay. I think that the problem is within the swap function since it doesn't crash if  I have it commented out.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap1(int& x, int& y)
{
    int tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = x;
}

int partition(int arr[], int cof, int length)
{
    int x = arr[length];
    int j = cof -1;
    for(int i = cof; length-1; i++ )
    {
        if(arr[i] <= x)
        {
            i++;
            swap1(arr[i], arr[j]);

        }
        swap1(arr[i+1], arr[length]);
    }
    return j++;
}


void quick_sort(int arr[], int cof, int length)
{
    if(cof < length)
    {
        int q = partition(arr, cof, length);
        quick_sort(arr,cof, q-1);
        quick_sort(arr,q+1, length);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1, 3, 2, 5, 4};
    quick_sort(arr, 1, 5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason of crash!

Your condition in `for` is weird:

```
for(int i = cof; length-1; i++ )
```

should be

```
for(int i = cof; i<length-1; i++ )
                 ^^
```

And correct your swap function:

```
void swap1(int& x, int& y)
{
    int tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp; // <-- use tmp
}
```

And many other bugs...

For example you're touching `arr[length]` many times which is out of bounds.

In addition, arrays start from `0` not `1` (see: `quick_sort(arr, 1, 5);`)

Comment: He has a lot of bugs, that's for sure.  Just these changes won't solve it, either.  +1.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your swap function is *wrong*, but it has nothing in it that would cause a crash by itself. The reason you don't see any crashes when you comment it out is that your program never writes to memory when `swap1` isn't part of the program.

Here's your swap function for reference:

```
void swap1(int& x, int& y)
{
    int tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = x;
}
```

Notice that you don't *use* `tmp` after assigning it.  I think you want the last line to be:

```
y = tmp;
```

Edit: Your program has other bugs, too.  For example, `arr[length]` is not an element of the array you create.

Comment: I removed this error, but there has to be something more; It still crashes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this line is causing your crash -

```
int partition(int arr[], int cof, int length)
{
    int x = arr[length];
```

You probably need to change it to

```
int partition(int arr[], int cof, int length)
{
    int x = arr[length-1];
```

In your example `main` function, you are creating an array of length 5, you pass 5 into the quick_sort function, which calls the partition with a length of 5. You then do `arr[5]` in the partition code, but the last element of the array is 4 since arrays are zero based indexing.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing swap wrong. change it to be:

```
void swap1(int& x, int& y)
{
    int tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;
}
```

you have also error with `arr[length]`, bad indexing. Your swap function is very special swap that instead of swaping elements at this moment result in `x` and `y` both with same value of `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Change swap fun. to:

```
void swap1(int& x, int& y)

{
    int tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;        <========= here
}
```

Of course it is not source of your problem.
This loop:

```
for (int i = cof; length-1; i++ )
```

looks like neverending story.. Update the condition to whatever you want.